# Using Resultset in Java Program

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

```
Resultset rs=stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from feedsca group by score order by score");
```

Using the above java code above, am retrieving the counts of rows from the table named feedsCA.

While trying to retrieving the counts using rs.getInt(1),rs.getInt(2),rs.getInt(3), I end with an error saying as below,

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.verifyResultSetHasCurrentRow(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getterGetColumn(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at SimpleMail.main(SimpleMail.java:151)
```

**UPDATE:**

The above exception has been resolved.

But I get the following exception, for which I dont know the reason. Please advise.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 2 is out of range.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.verifyValidColumnIndex(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getterGetColumn(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getInt(Unknown Source)
    at SimpleMail.main(SimpleMail.java:152)
```

This is how I have updated my program. Find me a logical way as I can understand well that the loop below will not work as required.

```
rs=stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from feedsca group by score order by score");
while(rs.next()){
pw.printf(rowFormat, rs.getLong(1),"0",rs.getLong(2),rs.getLong(3));}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to move the cursor of the result set to a row - either by `resultSet.first()` or by `resultSet.next()`. Initially the cursor is pointing before the first row, hence your exception.

When you want to iterate the `ResultSet`:

```
while(rs.next()) {
    ...
}
```

**Update:** For your second problem - (as noted by Casablanca) your query seems to return only one column, and you are asking for a 2nd and 3rd - and they are not found. Note that in `rs.getX(idx)` `idx` is the column, not the row.

Comment: Thanks Bozho! Kindly update me on my recent exception too. See my updated question

Comment: @LGAP: Your query is `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`, which returns only 1 value. Hence the only valid index is 1, that's why it complains that index 2 is out of range.

Comment: @LGAP: How do you know how many rows will be returned? It's not a good idea to hard-code the number of parameters to `printf`.

Comment: @Bozho.. My query actually returns three rows in one column. I need those three values to be retrieved. What can be done?

Comment: Simply remove rs.getLong(2) and 3. And check my update - these numbers are for columns, not for rows. Rows are iterated by `rs.next()`

Comment: @LGAP: See my updated answer for a way to do it, although I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `rs.next()` before accessing the first row.

Typically, you will iterate over the result set like this:

```
ResultSet rs = ...;
while (rs.next()) {
  ...
}
```

**Update:** Note that `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` returns only one field per row, which is the count. You may have several rows, but each row will have only one field, which has index 1. You need to iterate through the rows to get all the counts:

```
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
}
```

**Yet another update:** It's bad to assume that your query will always return only 3 rows. However, if you are absolutely sure of this, then you can just call `next` 3 times manually:

```
long l1, l2, l3;
rs.next();
l1 = rs.getLong(1);
rs.next();
l2 = rs.getLong(1);
rs.next();
l3 = rs.getLong(1);
pw.printf(rowFormat, l1,"0",l2,l3);
```

Comment: Thanks casablanca! In this case, am pretty sure that the query will return three rows only. I will go for an alternate method for any other queries with the similar scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use one of the methods to move the `ResultSet` cursor to a row before using the `getxxx` methods. i.e. `rs.next()`, `rs.first()` or `rs.last()`. These methods return `true` if a valid row has been located so a typical pattern is

```
if (rs.first()) {
  int field1 = rs.getInt(1); 
  // other columns
}
```

or for a query that returns multiple rows:

```
while (rs.next()) {
  int field1 = rs.getInt(1);
  // other columns
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge, your query will only get one row and column i.e., the total number of rows that your query returns.

Say for example :

Select count(*) from emp;
Generally this query will return a value 14.

so your java code

```
if(rs.next())
    rs.getInt(1);
```

will return only one value i.e., 14

So, How can you access rs.getString(2). This will automatically throws an exception which you got in the second case.